Windows transfer all settings made with mmc snap-in
I have 3 identical laptops, and I have to create identical environments for them. This includes adding snap-in with mmc. I did it on one of them - there a lot of settings: services auto run, messages for wrong password, disabling showing username on a blocked screen, disabling the remote control etc. So I stumbled across the issue that it seems like there is no way I can just save some file and transfer it to another PC. For services I had to export the list as xml using mmc and run a PowerShell script on a target computer. But it feels like I’m doing something wrong, there’s no way, I can’t just transfer my settings. Can someone please point me in a right direction?

Seems like you have configured a local group policy but have not used this name. Group policy related questions are better suited on Superuser.com as they are not really programming related.

If you have 3 identical laptops why dont you configure everything in one and then create an image of that computer and clone them in the 2 left?
